# Options for organizing android app with multiple independent apps

Tags: android, android-intent, maven-3

**Problem Definition:** We have a fairly large app which has multiple use cases such that they are all independent of each other. For example lets say we have a1, a2, a3 & a4 modules that are independent apps or use cases for our main app 'A'. The independent a1, a2, a3, a4 are all purchasable apps such that the user goes to our website instead of play store and activate either a1 or a2 by paying some fees on our website.

So basically App 'A' is a free app in play-store and is sort of Dashboard with buttons to launch a1, a2, a3, a4. When the user click on lets say a1 button then we will check if a1 is already installed and launch it but if it is not present then give the user a link to download it.

**Option 1:** Have a main app 'A' and a1, a2, a3, a4 as library project. But with this approach the main app A is too big in size.

**Option 2:** Have a1, a2, a3, a4 build as separate .apk and then put in the assets folder of main app 'A' and then install them as needed. Again size of main app A is bigger.

**Option 3:** Upload a1, a2, a3, a4 to a third party website or play store and download from it as needed. This way the main app remains lighter.

**Observation:** In all these approaches there will be an independent app installed with its own icon on users phone. So basically user can launch from either the Dashboard (which will eventually launch an intent from Activity in a1 app) or user can directly launch app a1.

**Follow-up Question:** Is there any other solution that anyone can suggest to tackle this kind of problem? Another things is by going this approach app a1, a2, a3, a4 can be developed & tested independently of each other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For what it's worth, I'd go with option 3 to Play Store. That's the easiest to manage and the most well known. Much more trusted than non-Google sites. 'Course they do like that 30%...

For your follow up I'm assuming Eclipse. If you use something else, do something similar.

When you move something to production, create a release package (folder). In the package are:

1. The APK
2. An exported file structure that includes .classpath, source, etc. This can be imported as a project.
3. Any support files such as icon sets, raw data, etc.
4. a copy of the keystore used for signing.
5. a copy of your final sdcard image.
6. Copies of the marketing information put in Play Store.

Back it up multiple times to different drives. I burn a DVD as well.

When you work on the next release, copy what you need to a new, pending release package. Do not modify the current release package.
Create a new workspace.
Copy the sdcard to the sdcard folder.
Benchmark during development by renaming the current file structure and then exporting the file structure with the changes.

During development, at least once a day make copies of the workspace file structure using export. It only takes seconds.

Add to this procedure as needed. The idea is that before you post to Play Store, you ensure that everything is saved to a release package including the apk. Then make No changes to the package. If you have errors on the production versions, start a new release.

This is all standard programming practices. You probably know all of this already. The problem is enforcing the rules. You know your environment better that anybody. All you have to do is study what components can be placed in a release package that will allow you to duplicate that envonemnt at a later date. Then you have to enforce the rules. Or make yourself follow them.

People have a tendency to make a quick fix or change to the source code and build over the top of the last production environment. Nobody wants to follow the rules at 2 am. You may have to resort to physical violence (know Wing Chun?). Or maybe send Guido around to ensure the rules are followed.

Have fun. Do a study. Ask all of your staff what it would take to restore to original status if you had a hard disk crash. That's what goes in your release package. (It's also what you should be backing up on a daily basis.)

Well, I've rambled on long enough telling you what you already know. Hopefully I've triggered some ideas. Ya'll be good, ya hear.

Comment: Ooops. I left the impression that you rename the file structure in the development environment. Not what I intended. Rename the file sturcture at the target end. Then export to the target.

Comment: Thanks Howard for your reply. I will discuss with my team and most probably we are anyways leaning towards option 3 with play store. We just wanted to confirm that we are not one off in doing so and it seems that people are already doing this kind of approach.